# Why does my popup modal not close after redirecting to a different page?

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I have created a popup modal that has the options "Shop Now" and "Close". Both options are working but when the Shop Now button redirects to the page Ive linked it to, the popup modal is still showing up in the background. I have tried window.close() and return false; but neither have worked. I am fairly new to jQuery and I am not sure what other way to go about this. I have provided my HTML and jQuery below, as well as a live version of my error.

https://jsfiddle.net/getMecoffee56/grnbocjd/

HTML

```
<div id="popup_box">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0569/4201/t/9/assets/b66ede311b21409cb9d306d75b121aa8.png?38140025230256355" alt="" height="250" width="180" align="left">
  <h1>$30 off the purchase of $130 and Free Shipping on order of $29 and up.</h1>
  <h2>Try code: ALZI2017</h2>
  <br>

  <button id="shop"><a href="https://www.alzerina.com/collections/ready-to-wear">Shop Now</a></button>
  <button id="buttonClose">Close</button>

</div>
```

JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //hide hider and popup_box

    $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");

    //on click show the hider div and the message
    $("#showpopup").click(function () {


    });
    //on click hide the message
    $("#buttonClose").click(function () {


        $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
    });

   $("#shop").click(function () {


        $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide JQuery code that actually _does what you say it does?_

Comment: you got any error in console ??

Comment: @JamesDouglas I edited my code there was an error. please check it out here working.  https://jsfiddle.net/getMecoffee56/grnbocjd/

Comment: @Rush.2707 nope no errors are appearing.

Comment: There is still no `#hider` element, and don't use `<center>` in html5.

Comment: @JamesDouglas #hider was a previous element added by somebody else working on this. However I removed it because it was just an empty div.

Comment: @JamesDouglas Ive removed the center tags (although this is nothing that is affecting my ACTUAL issues) and the unnecessary hide element.